# Replace back button with menu if no page to go back - Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm developing an ionic app on android. I'm facing a problem where back button doesn't show up when there's no page to go back.

For more detailed explanation:
**Scenario 1**: Button from side menu when click go to View B.
**Scenario 2**: Button from side menu to View A, then button from View A to View B.

**Scenario 2** View B shows back button, since it has a previous page,  but **Scenario 1** doesn't have a previous page that's why it doesn't show the back button, How do I display the menu button if there's no back button?

Here's my code below:

```
<ion-view view-title="MY View">
    <ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button" type="submit" 
        ng-click="goEdit(data.ID)">Edit</button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-content class="has-header">

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Additional Info:

When removing the `<ion-nav-bar>` it displays the menu button, but of course will no longer show back button and edit button.  When I try putting **ng-hide** in `<ion-nav-bar ng-hide="isMenu">` it doesn't show any nav-bar since it's hidden but from html inspect element it's still there but hidden only.  Any work around on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you set a page as a rootPage and also use menu in  you will see menu button. when navigating to another page from root if you use `navCtrl.push()` back button will automatically be added to the pushed view.if you set second page as a rootPage again you will see menu button again.
But if you want to implement it yourself that is another thing.
also check this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/)

Answer (score -1):

Consider customizing the navbar/toolbar only for the pages that needs it.

By having an ion-toolbar in the ion-header, it appears on top of the default ion-navbar. So it is a workaround to have a custom header bar with my close icon and my custom function gotoHome(). That's the best way i found to customize the 'navbar' for a particular page.

```html
<ion-header>

    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons left>
            <button ion-button icon-only (click)="gotoHome()">
                <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Title</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    ...
</ion-content>
```

The same answer applies to this topic, for reference :
[Ionic Change back button icon for one page only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217442/ionic-change-back-button-icon-for-one-page-only/46422849#46422849)